# Macaulay's example of prime ideals in $\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ having large number of generators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

There is a famous example of Macaulay which shows that there are prime ideals of height two in $\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ having at least $l$ generators for any $l\ge 3$.

In Macaulay's words, the example is constructed as follows: 
"*Consider $l(l-1)/2$ straight lines through the origin $O$ in $3$-dimensional space, not lying on any cone of order $l-2$. Draw a cone of order $l$ and a surface (not a cone) of order $l$ through the $l(l-1)/2$ lines so as to intersect again in an irreducible curve of order $l(l+1)/2$ with $l(l-1)/2$ tangents at $O$. Then no basis of the prime module determined by this curve can have less than $l$ members, where $l$ is a number which can be chosen as high as we please.*"

> I'd be grateful if someone can "translate" the above in an algebraic language.

(In [this paper](http://www.math.unipd.it/~frank/ALGANT/2010/projects/macaulay-examplex.pdf) one can find more details and a proof, but the language is also geometric.)

Comment: Posted previously on M.SE at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285065/macaulays-example-of-prime-ideals-in-mathbb-cx-1-x-2-x-3-having-large-numb

Comment: Does anybody have a precise definition of "cone" and "cone of order $l$"? looks like it's of very old use, but I couldn't find a definition.

Comment: @YCor Maybe the linked paper of Abhyankar could shed some light, but definitely I'm  not the one who can spot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some terminology drift here. I would say that "order" would be called degree in modern terminology, for example.

Here is the way I see it, and please someone correct me if I am wrong.

Take $l(l-1)/2$ lines through the origin in $\mathbb C^3$, 
i.e. ideals $I_i\subset\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ of 
the form $\langle X_2-\alpha_iX_1,X_3-\beta_i X_1\rangle $ with $1\leq i\leq l(l-1)/2$ and 
$\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ generic (so that no degree $l-2$ homogeneous polynomial in $X_1,X_2,X_3$ lies in all of the above ideals $I_i$).

Consider a polynomial $F_1$ which is homogeneous of degree $l$ and is contained in each $I_i$. Containment in $I_i$ is a codimension one condition, and there is a 
dimension $(l+1)(l+2)/2$ space of degree $l$ polynomials, so such $F_1$ exists. I assume that such $F_1$ is chosen generically (this is the "cone").

Consider a polynomial $F_2$ which does not have to be homogeneous, but rather is a sum of polynomials of degrees $\geq l$ which is contained in all $I_i$ (and presumably is generic with respect to this property).

Then the ideal in question is the radical of $\langle F_1,F_2\rangle$.

I don't claim to know how the actual argument proceeds, but this looks like the algebraic translation you are after.

Comment: "Order" means "order of vanishing at the origin". "Cone" means stable under linear maps $(X_i\to\lambda X_i)$.